# MYSQL SELECT with id compared against FLOOR RAND returns one, more than one and none rows

Tags: mysql

With given table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE `people` (
  `id` integer auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(20),
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `people` (`name`) VALUES ('John'), ('Emma'), ('George'), ('Barry'), ('Lisa'), ('Bob'), ('Olivia');
```

A query:

```
SET @all = (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `people`);    
SELECT * FROM `people` WHERE `id` = FLOOR(1 + RAND() * @all);
```

Results in:

```
id  name
2   Emma
5   Lisa
```

or

```
id  name
3   George
4   Barry
```

or

```
id  name
5   Lisa
```

or

```
id  name
1   John
6   Bob
```

sometimes result has 3 rows

```
id  name
3   George
4   Barry
7   Olivia
```

once I got result with 4 rows

```
id  name
4   Barry
5   Lisa
6   Bob
7   Olivia
```

or empty result

When I check the value generated by the expression `FLOOR(1 + RAND() * @all)` it appears to be integer value, eg. `5`, not a decimal.

But when I store the value to a variable first and then use the variable in the query, the result is as expected, always one row:

```
SET @r = FLOOR(1 + RAND() * @all);
SELECT * FROM `people` WHERE `id` = @r;
```

I guess that when I store the result of FLOOR into a variable it gets converted, but how does mysql compares a value that in result it is equal to many different ones, my first guess was it is rounded somehow, but when I got values that delta of which is > 4 then my next guess would be some bit comparison and decimal bit representation shenanigans, but I have no idea.

Comment: This is the wrong approach to select a random record.  There *WILL* be gaps between your IDs! Always consilder this. Read:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/19422/43959

Comment: `FLOOR(1 + RAND() * @all)` is evaluated for every row in the `WHERE` clause so you can get multiple matches. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45656145/rand-in-where-clause-in-mysql

Comment: @Kaii, I won't use it, I've used offset with limit, that was just for the question purposes.

Comment: @Nick, That makes sense, thanks.